# nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, servletcontextlistener

After some update I started getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
2023-04-10 02:41:11.660 [main] INFO  c.o.w.s.i.LoggableDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
2023-04-10 02:41:21.120 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#denominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.122 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#validationResult; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.122 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#additionalInfo; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.156 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#paymentDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.156 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#denominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.156 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#retransmitDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.157 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#acceptorDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:21.160 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.FavoritePaymentEntity_#properties; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:27.130 [main] WARN  c.o.i.s.firebase.FirebaseServiceImpl - FirebaseCredentialsPath is empty. Push notification doesn't work.
2023-04-10 02:41:32.301 [main] INFO  c.o.w.s.i.LoggableDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 20639 ms
2023-04-10 02:41:45.771 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#validationResult; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.773 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#additionalInfo; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.773 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.PaymentEntity_#denominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.803 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#acceptorDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.803 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#retransmitDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.803 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#denominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.803 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.CollectionTerminalEntity_#paymentDenominations; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:45.806 [main] ERROR o.h.m.internal.MetadataContext - HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : com.openpayment.impl.entity.FavoritePaymentEntity_#properties; expected type :  org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.SingularAttributeImpl; encountered type : javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute
2023-04-10 02:41:51.329 [main] WARN  c.o.i.s.e.ElcartTokenServiceImpl - Security provider BouncyCastle already installed!
2023-04-10 02:41:51.392 [main] WARN  c.o.i.s.firebase.FirebaseServiceImpl - FirebaseCredentialsPath is empty. Push notification doesn't work.
2023-04-10 02:42:04.536 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

The update included the adding the dependency in the pom file:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

How to fix it or work it around?